# How can I store some sets of numbers as IDs in a column in database and then get them one by one?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store some sets of numbers as file IDs in just one column and put a "," after them to make them separate. 
like : 8546, 5654, 2311, 7544, 6565, ....
But in retrieving them, I want to get each ID separately. Is it possible?

Comment: Please don't store data like that. Store each in a separate record.

Comment: Not if they're all listed in one column. Not with MySQL solely anyway.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Is it just with SQL queries or are you using C# or another language? Like "select id from database"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using Mysql databases.

Comment: This is not recommended.May be you can explain the requirement, that made you arrive at this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

store the data as set in database column (mysql) and use explode function in php to read the set from the column. however it is not a good idea to stor data like that, you must stor each in a separate column, you can create another table with the forain key to the parent table and stort these id's on that table.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have another table with the `id`s  then you can SELECT id FROM this table and that table, if you want to do it with MySQL only.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just mysql, try regular expressions:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html
```

I don't understand what you are doing or why you would do this, but that's what I would do. Use some type of counter to keep track of which comma you are at, and prepend to the regex for the amount the counter is at.

This is if it is just mysql, if you've got php, c#, java, python, any other language, you can tokenize.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but it's not recommended 99%.

you can do this exploding, I.E:

```
insert into table1(id) values ("1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9")
```

the ID field cannot be a number field type, probably a varchar could be a good option.  for Mysql those values will be more text than number.

**BUT**

if you do that you are making it wrong, because.

- You are not making a relational database.
- You are losing the index, and the search will be slower.
- you are creating dependence in your code, if you want to upgrade, add new things it's not going to be easy at all.

please take a look to Entity relation modeling, or E/R Model

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep this functionality in the database, you could use a procedure. [Here is an example](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=4) that splits a string and inserts it into a table. If you want to do it in one call, you'd want to create the table as a `TEMPORARY TABLE` within the procedure, select from it to return the results from within the procedure, and then drop it before exiting.

*for it to work for me, I needed to remove the COMMENT part.*